# Visio 2010: Mass-applying properties (font, line, etc.) to shapes

Tags: themes, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

I am using Visio 2010 to create some large figures and I am wondering how to group various shapes by some property so that I can easily change it later for all of them.

I'd like something similar to [color by value](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/enhance-your-data-with-data-graphics-HA010379394.aspx?CTT=1) for modifying all theme properties (font, line, etc.) according to some "value" of each specific shape.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the **Styles** feature in Visio will what you want. You can define a style in Visio and the style to any number of shapes. Later, you can edit the style and the changes will appear on all the shapes that are using that style.

The **Styles** feature is available in Visio 2003, Visio 2007 and Visio 2010

I have a blog post written on enabling the Style Explorer in Visio 2007 and Visio 2010 that you may find useful in getting started.